# MySQL Add column while joining with MIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I got problems with MySQLs way of handling joins.

I'm trying to take out a small amount of info from a table and group it together, and then add the rest of the info. Something like this:

```
 id    |   pack   |   period   |  name
----   |  ------  |  --------  | ------
 50    |   p1     |    t1      |  test1
 51    |   p2     |    q2      |  test2
 52    |   p3     |    q2      |  testt3
 53    |   p4     |    t1      |  pest4
 54    |   p1     |    t1      |  test5
```

I want it to get out sorted like:

```
 id    |   pack   |   period   |  name
----   |  ------  |  --------  | ------
 50    |   p1     |    t1      |  test1
 54    |   p1     |    t1      |  test5
 53    |   p4     |    t1      |  pest4
 51    |   p2     |    q2      |  test2
 52    |   p3     |    q2      |  testt3
```

Where I get the order by:

- MIN(id) period - First Sort
- MIN(id) package - Second Sort

What I've tried yet:

```
SELECT t1.pack, t1.period, t1.name 
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MIN(id) as minID, period
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY pack
) t2
ON t1.period = t2.period
ORDER BY t2.minID
```

Comment: What is your full query?

Comment: plz share your schema structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own answer, made it far too hard for myself:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.pack, t1.period, t1.name
FROM (
TABLE1 t1
JOIN (
SELECT *, MIN(id) as minID 
FROM TABLE1 t2
GROUP BY t2.period) t2
ON t2.period= t1.period
) ORDER BY minID, pack
```

People should understand that this is not a optimal way to solve the problem if you have the option to build your own database structure. But when you are forced to stick to a specific structure, this at least works! Hope it helps someone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

**What is your query currently doing?**

```
SELECT t1.pack, t1.period, t1.name 
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MIN(id) as minID, period
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY pack
) t2
ON t1.period = t2.period
ORDER BY t2.minID
```

First, we are finding the necessary data from table1. This is fine. Next, you have a left join on table1. In this left join, you are finding the minimum id for the given period. The problem is what this looks like.

> ```
>  id    |   pack   |   period   |  name  |  t2.minID
> ----   |  ------  |  --------  | ------ | ----------
>  50    |   p1     |    t1      |  test1 |  50
>  54    |   p1     |    t1      |  test5 |  50
>  53    |   p4     |    t1      |  pest4 |  50
>  51    |   p2     |    q2      |  test2 |  51
>  52    |   p3     |    q2      |  testt3|  51
> ```

Since you are doing the full outer join on the period alone, sql is going to find the minimum id for the period and then set that id as the value for all of the data in the period, as you can see by the table above. The way your query stands, everything in period t1 will come before everything in q2 because 50<51. However, sql will then sort the data in each period however it wants. So, some times the output might be what is shown above, but each time it will be ordered differently.

**How can you fix this?**

Sql already knows how to order things. You don't need to supply it with a minimum value, only the column that you wish to sort by. Sql defaults to sorting the data in ascending order, but you can specify to sort in descending order by tacking on `desc` at the end of your order by.

For your query, I would recommend taking out the left outer join (since it looks like you only included it for the order by and removing it will increase performance). Then, change the order by to be what you specified in your question, `t1.period, t1.pack`

```
SELECT  t1.pack, t1.period, t1.name 
FROM    TABLE1 t1
ORDER BY t1.period, t1.pack
```

If you have more than one column in your order by, sql will use the first column to sort by. Then if there is anything that has the same value for the first column, sql will default to the second column.

Comment: Hi! I was trying to post an answer to my own question yesterday once I found it, but it failed (guess I have too few credits). The way you order wont solve my problem if I lets say have a period called another_time1 that is after time1, since it order by letters. That was the whole reason behind the question with how to order on the smallest id, but as I said, I found the answer: `SELECT t1.id, t1.pack, t1.period, t1.nameFROM (TABLE1 t1JOIN (SELECT *, MIN(id) as minIDFROM TABLE1 t2GROUP BY t2.period) t2 ON t2.period= t1.period ) ORDER BY minID, pack`

Comment: @user2687506 I understand now. You are trying to order the periods based on whichever has the smallest id. I would still recommend against this because you are creating a self-join in order to change the ordering. Often you can more optimally order the data in other code. Also, I don't really agree with using the ids as any sort of information except what they are meant to be, ids. However, I can recognize that some specifications may be outside of your control. You should be able to answer the question after it has been 24 hours since you asked it (or something like that).

Comment: I totally understand that it's far from optimal both using ids as more than keys and doing self-joins. Unfourtunatley I haven't found anyone/anything that can point me in a better direction. The problem is that I need to order the periods based on when they were inserted into the table (which is a bad creation from the start, but nothing I really can do anything about.. Using multiple systems with multiple users creates problems).